My Asset Browser's sub-folders are missing
I work on two different computers and have been using an external hard drive to store my Blender assets. In the Asset browser, I set it up, so I had a primary folder for low-poly models and a primary folder for the mid to high-resolution models. The asset browser folder with mid to high-resolution models is still there but all the sub-folders are gone and all the models are now unassigned. The models are still assets, but the folder structure is gone. I didn’t change the location of any of the files on the hard drive. I’ve been using the hard drive with both computers and never had any problems till now. Why would all the sub-folders disappear? How can I restore the file structure and prevent this from happening again?

To keep track of what catalog an asset is part of, blender assigns an UUID (unique identifier) to each catalog, then any object assigned to that catalog is given that UUID.
This way you can rename and reorganize your catalogs freely, and Blender doesn't need to keep track of changes to know which assets belong to which catalog.
The downside being that if the UUIDs don't match you assets won't show up in the expected catalogs.
Which I suspect is what happened here, somehow you probably assigned your assets to non matching catalog IDs on different computers.
You can open your blender_assets.cats.txt that resides at the root folder of your asset library and check with a plain text editor the catalog UUIDs which shoudl read something like
ef3bd91a-49b3-4c3e-b8e6-8327b6e05587:Cars:Cars
e813584e-7fcd-46ce-ae87-10ff6a56d620:Cars/Racing
b1f830b9-e015-4070-b016-879ebc0e7728:Cars/All Terrain
d2f399f8-8e30-4957-bc21-3461696f11aa:Vegetation:Vegetation
ea651808-742e-46f6-8fa8-84a9fea15e47:Vegetation/Trees

Check the first long hash string and see if they match the assets in the Blender file.
In the Blender Outliner change the view on top to Data API, then brown to one of the misplaced assets, depending on type they will be under either Collection, Object, Node Tree, etc.


From there expand the category Asset Data and look for a Catalog UUID and see if it matches the one on blender_assets.cats.txt which likely wont.
I don't know of any way to easily change that in the Blender file en mass, other that programmatically through scripting, but if all assets are misplaced equally, you can probably change the catalog UUIDs more easily in the catalog txt file itself.
